# determine the cost if given volume and (height to diameter) ratio

Tags: analysis, optimization, economics

if a can made out a thin sheet of tin , which cost about 0.25$ per square meter .
my question is for various height to diameter ratio ( H/D )  values and several can volumes (V), what is the equation used to calculate the cost ?

what is  my equation to calculate cost ?

answer :
 if h/d=x then h=x*d.....1

volume of cylinder  = pi*r^2*h= pi*r^2*xd  ,where r=d/2

if volume is given then

d=(v*4/(pi*x))^1/3......2

then surface area =(2*pi*r^2)+2*pi*r*h......3

substitute with 1 and 2 in 3 and then multiply them with the cost value for meter square.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: thank you . thought to myself  that cost = volume * 0.25 but i dont know how to involve height to diameter and how its related